# How to find a node outside of the parent in get_node function?

Tags: nodes, parent-child, parent, godot, gdscript

Im using Godot Engine, i have encountered a problem. I want to acess a node outside of my parent i assigned the script to.
[image: My current nodes]

I have assigned my script to player and i need to access ThirdPersonCamera. But i cant move ThirdPersonCamera into player because its an interpolated camera and needs to move freely.

> onready var camera1 = get_node("Head/FirstPersonCamera")

This is my first camera which i can acess, because its a child. But how do i access the ThirdPersonCamera?

Comment: Have you tried `get_tree().get_root().get_node("ThirdPersonCamera")`?

Answer (score 0):

```
onready var camera2 = get_node("../ThirdPersonCamera")
```

The .. will select the parent node and from there you can select the child of the parent and in this case the camera node